# Function behaves differently when stepping through to when stepping over

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, naudio

I'm having a problem with my unit testing of a function employing NAudio's PinkNoiseGenerator.

The behaviour of the createPinkNoiseGeneratorLists function seems to be pretty much as expected when stepping through the program - that is to say that the receiverGeneratorList (see below) is populated with lists of PinkNoiseGenerators, each of which contains a list of samples which, crucially, all have different values:

[image: Stepping Through]
[image: Stepping Through]

The problem occurs when stepping over the function. The receiverGeneratorList is still populated with lists of PinkNoiseGenerators, but the samples are identically-valued:

[image: Stepping Over]
[image: Stepping Over]

The second behaviour is unwanted. I need the pink noise generators to be differently-valued, both in testing and when the program is run. I have narrowed the behaviour down to the following nested for-loop (full code at the bottom):

```
for (int j = 0; j < receiverList[i].AmplitudeCurveList.Count; j++)
{
    // Calculate duration of pink noise in seconds

    double time = receiverList[i].AmplitudeCurveList[j].Count / (double)sampleRate;

    // Instantiate new generator (list of pink noise samples) at given duration

    PinkNoiseGenerator generator = new PinkNoiseGenerator(time, sampleRate, outputFileName, numberOfChannels);

    // Add generator to generator list which will then be added to the list of lists of pink noise generators,

    generatorList.Add(generator);
}
```

I can't see anything immediately wrong with the code - could this be a timing issue with NAudio? I've googled round the issue, which seems quite rare but the people who have experienced similar sometimes get responses to do with multithreading - I'm not using any multithreading myself but admittedly there might be some going on 'under the hood' in NAudio.

I have also had a look through the 'similar questions' in the sidebar and they are mostly not similar. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286227/c-sharp-list-manipulation-output-different-when-stepping-through-vs-running) question's top answer alludes to a seeding issue - I thought a similar thing may be to blame for my problem, and understand the concept, but am unsure how to apply it to my specific problem - could my issue be to do with how the pink noise is seeded? I'm really not sure how to debug an error like this.

My system is running:

Windows 7 64-Bit

VS2013 v12.0.21005.1

NET v4.6.01055

---

Below is the full test/function code if it will help solve the problem:

Here is the (abridged) test class:

```
[TestMethod]
public void testPinkNoise()
{
    string outputFileName = @"C:\Users\Mick\Test\\Output\Test.wav";
    int numberOfChannels = 1;
    int sampleRate = 1000;

    // Act

    // Problem with identical PinkNoiseGenerators occurs here -> timing issue with NAudio?

    receiverGeneratorList = scene.createPinkNoiseGeneratorLists(sampleRate, outputFileName, numberOfChannels); 
}
```

And here is the function itself (for the record, I know the variable names are confusing and the function in general is in dire need of refactoring for clarity/readability, what with it's lists of lists of curves and whatnot - haven't gotten round to it yet):

```
public List<List<PinkNoiseGenerator>> createPinkNoiseGeneratorLists(int sampleRate, string outputFileName, int numberOfChannels)
{
    // Initialise list of lists of pink noise samples

    List<List<PinkNoiseGenerator>> receiverGeneratorList = new List<List<PinkNoiseGenerator>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < receiverList.Count; i++)
    {
        List<PinkNoiseGenerator> generatorList = new List<PinkNoiseGenerator>();

        // For every amplitude curve within the receiver, generate a corresponding pink noise curve

        for (int j = 0; j < receiverList[i].AmplitudeCurveList.Count; j++)
        {
            // Calculate duration of pink noise in seconds

            double time = receiverList[i].AmplitudeCurveList[j].Count / (double)sampleRate;

            // Instantiate new generator (list of pink noise samples) at given duration

            PinkNoiseGenerator generator = new PinkNoiseGenerator(time, sampleRate, outputFileName, numberOfChannels);

            // Add generator to generator list which will then be added to the list of lists of pink noise curves,

            generatorList.Add(generator);
        }

        // Add list of pink noise curves 

        receiverGeneratorList.Add(generatorList);
    }

    return receiverGeneratorList;
}
```

Comment: It totally sounds like a threading issue. Have you tried wrapping the code in `createPinkNoiseGeneratorLists` with a `lock` statement?

Comment: And yes, I understand you are not doing any threading. Just try it.

Comment: Taking a second look at your code, how are you generating the `receiverList`? This line caught my eye. It could return the same value depending on how you initialize `receiverList`: `double time = receiverList[i].AmplitudeCurveList[j].Count / (double)sampleRate;`

Comment: I'll try the lock statement and get back to you. receiverList is populated from a .csv file - can't post the code in the comments but I'm fairly sure this isn't the problem

Comment: Double-check the seed data. Make sure you are not using the same value to initialize `time`. It looks like it shouldn't make a difference, but when you encounter situations like this, you gotta try everything... :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Unfortunately the lock statement didn't work, and any seeding that's occurring would be happening within the NAudio library (which holds the PinkNoiseGenerator),which I didn't write so I'm a little apprehensive about doing anything to its code lest I break anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NAudio generates internally a random number generator, taking the time as seed value. When you step over the function, the two `new PinkNoiseGenerator()` calls happen so fast that the time hasn't changed and the same seed value was used. To verify this, try to call `Thread.Sleep(1000)` after the `new PinkNoiseGenerator()` call and see if it made a difference.

If that's indeed the problem, you can consider two alternatives:

1. Placing an intentional delay in the code so that subsequent constructor calls of `PinkNoiseGenerator` happen in different timestamps
2. Creating just one Generator (one random seed), and read all the buffers from it.

Comment: I'll test using the Sleep method now. I'd rather not extend the execution time of the program any more than necessary, so Option 2 seems to be my best bet if it does turn out to be the case - do you mean I would need to create a Generator with (time * desired number of Generators) samples and then parse into separate buffers after?

Comment: Exactly. If that's possible, it'll probably be the fastest way.

Comment: Righto. I've accepted your answer as sleeping for even a handful of milliseconds fixes the problem.